# Displaying files in a folder, first file is not displayed

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following code which displays file names in a specified folder. But, when there is only one file in the folder, that file is not displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

```php
$files = glob("images/properties/*.*");

for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo '$image';
}
```

Comment: `$i <= count($files)`?

Answer (score 2):

PHP indexes arrays from `0`. Since you're starting your loop at `1`, you're always skipping the first matched file. ANd in fact, your for() loop is pointless, you could just as well do

```
foreach($files as $i => $file) {
 ...
}
```

and not have to worry about counting or terminating the loop properly.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting your loop from 1 rather than 0 and you're echoing the string of `$image` rather than it's contents by using single quotes (`'`):

```
$files = glob("images/properties/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo "$image\n";
}
```

in terms of efficiency, you should use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach(glob("images/properties/*.*") as $value){
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your for from 0:

```
  for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
```

because if there is only a file, count($files) is 1 so it exit from for